# How to check if a message exists? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have got an embed manager here, and I want to check if the embed exists. I delete it after it got sent, and if someone else deletes it before that, I get a DiscordAPI error. I've tried several things, but never got a solution. Can you help?

This is my code:

```js
    error(channel, title, content) {
        var message
        var embed = new MessageEmbed() 
            .setColor(COLORS.red)
            .setDescription(content)
        if(title) {
            embed.setTitle(title)
        }
        channel.send(' ', embed).then((m) => {
            message = m
            try {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if(MESSAGE EXISTS) {
                        m.delete()
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                }, 5500);
            } catch(e) {
            }

        })
        return message

    },
```

Edited:

```js
    error(channel, title, content) {
        var message
        var embed = new MessageEmbed() 
            .setColor(COLORS.red)
            .setDescription(content)
        if(title) {
            embed.setTitle(title)
        }
        channel.send(' ', embed).then((m) => {
            message = m
            try {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    try {
                        channel.messages.fetch(m.id)
                      .then(m => console.log(m.content)) //it fetched the message - good
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    }
                }, 5500);
            } catch(e) {
            }

        })
        return message

    },
```

stack trace:

```
DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (D:\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async MessageManager._fetchId (D:\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\MessageManager.js:135:18) {
  method: 'get',
  path: '/channels/797648418104934470/messages/798863571924418562',
  code: 10008,
  httpStatus: 404
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Discord Bot
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node main.js debug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make it more difficult than needed. `.send`, `.fetch`, and `.delete` all return a promise. It means you can (and should) use the `catch` method to catch any errors. You don't need to use try-catch blocks, unless you want to use `async/await` instead of `.then/catch`.

Check the code below, I've added all the `catch`es. Check how it catches the error when the message doesn't exists (checking the `err.httpStatus`), or when the message can't be deleted for any other reason.

```js
channel.send(embed)
  .then((sentMessage) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      channel.messages
        .fetch(sentMessage.id)
        .then((fetchedMessage) => {
          console.log('Message exists');

          fetchedMessage
            .delete()
            .then(() => console.log('Message deleted successfully'))
            .catch((err) => console.log('Could not delete the message', err));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          if (err.httpStatus === 404) {
            console.log('Message already deleted');
          } else {
            console.log(err);
          }
        });
    }, 5000);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The API error is caused by discord trying to delete a message that doesnt exist (you have already deleted it). Try to resolve the promise by fetching the id of the embed in a try catch statement, then going from there - this way you avoid the API error.

```js
try {
    channel.messages.fetch(message.id)
  .then(message => console.log(message.content)) //it fetched the message - good
} catch (error) {
    return; //the message no longer exists and will be ignored
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried to fetch the message several times, but i failed. Can you help?

Comment: Of course, I will edit my answer to suggest a fix, give me just a minute

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: Thank you very much! The error gets catched now, and my bot is not crashing

Comment: Excellent! Please mark the answer as correct by clicking on the tick mark on the left side

Comment: Oh. i thought it worked... On the first try, the bot did not crash but i got the stack strace. But in the second try the bot crashed

Comment: How strange, replace the `return` with a `console.log(error)` and let me know what it says

Comment: In the console i get the DiscordAPI error (unknown message)

Comment: I edited my question, there you can see the code i use now

Comment: Good, now run the command and the error will be logged so we can fix whatever is going wrong - does it say where the error in the code is? Usually is in the form `filename.js - 23:53` for example

Comment: It does not say where the error is. When i dont delete the embed manually, the code does what i want. but when i delete it manually, it tries to fetch and i get the discordapi error. I added the stacktrace to the question

Comment: Add my discord: Protocol#0001 where we can continue this

Answer (score 0):

so I have had a similar issue and I think my solution to it might be aplicable to your problem.

```
 function msgExists(channelID, messageID){


/*get channel*/
const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID); //(get channel)

/*get channel messages*/
channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 }).then(messages => {
    let count = 0;
    let max = (messages.length - 1);
    //Iterate through the messages.
    messages.forEach(message => {                                   
                                    
                                    if (messageID === message.id){
                                        console.log("message found");
                                    }
                                    if (count == (max)){
                                        console.log("message could not be found");
                                    }
                                    
                                    count++;
                                });
    

  });
```

}